# Changing Observable Property of One Object Changes Property of All In Collection

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a collection of objects in my view model. I'm experiencing an issue when binding a value to `select` control. The value is a JS object and not a primitive type. When I have more than one object in the bound collection and change the `select` control, all of the other object's values update to the newly selected one. It's like all of the values are bound to the same instance inside the `foreach` binding. The error only seems to happen when new rows are inserted, not when simply editing existing ones.

I have striped out a lot of the complexities and have an example showing the issue on JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zero21xxx/5vgDy/

**Steps to see the Error**

1. Select Settle Type from the drop down of row 1
2. Select "Two" from the new drop down to the right.
3. Select Settle Type from the drop down of row 2
4. Both row 1 and row 2 will now both be set to "One" in the select box.

I would expect that a change in one row would not effect any of the other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all a bit complicated how you have it setup, however, I think the problem is, that your ids are not what you expect,

```
 function getValues(tabId) {
                console.log("tabId " + tabId);
                if (lookUp[tabId]) {
```

if I add that to your code,  it show's the same tabId, which means you are dealing with the same objects by the looks of it.

if I change getValues so each time it does

```
 function getValues(tabId) {
                console.log("tabId " + tabId);
                return  [new DatabaseField(nextId(), "Name", "Attorney Name", DataType.STRING.id),
                                                             new DatabaseField(nextId(), 
"Type", "Settle Type", DataType.DROPDOWN.id)];
}
```

also I changed all the observables with [] to observable arrays...

then it seems to work.  fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/wmxJX/

Answer (score 1):

Each time that you choose a different `selectedDatabaseField` it rebuilds the `availableOptions.options`.  Each of the rows are bound against these same options as choices.  When the options are rebuilt, then each row's selected value is no longer a valid choice.

Even if the object looks exactly the same it is not equal unless it is a reference to the same object.

So, since the options have changed and the currently selected value is no longer valid, the `value` binding will assign the first option as the value (unless you have an optionsCaption specified).

So, you probably don't want to rebuild the options, if they are already built or you would want separate options for each row rather than binding against the same database field object.

Comment: What would you suggest in terms of code change to solve this? I really do want to cache the `DatabaseField` information because it's going to eventually be hitting a server.

Also, why does this same effect not happen with regard to the `availableTabs`? All of the items in the `foreach` are bound to the parent's list of tabs, but they can be changed without impacting other rows in the table.

Comment: Probably something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5vgDy/54/.  Just check if the options are already populated on the field rather than repopulate them each time.